# Running Allegro 5 on other computers

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

I have made an allegro simple game . But when I open the *.exe file on another computer it says that there are many missing .dll files . How can I make my game to run on other computers without Visual Studio and Allegro 5 library installed ?

Comment: Add the missing DLL's to the same directory where your .exe is.

Comment: But there are a lot of dlls missing . Isn't there a way to include them at once ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Longer version of my comment:

When you created your application, it links to certain DLL's that exist on your computer. When you distribute your game, you will either need to ZIP the DLL's along with your .exe or package them using package creators and ship it.

The best way to find which DLL's your exe depends on will be to use a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). You don't need to copy absolutely all DLL's that your EXE depends on. Only the ones that you see are in non-standard paths like ones that are not in C:\Windows\System32. That being said, you **might need to** copy some from C:\Windows\System32. You will need to find that out on your own.

To package them all as a setup, you can use package creators like [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). Otherwise, create a script that ZIPs it all up for you. AFAIK, there is no easy way to get all DLL's required that are missing from the other persons' system. You'll need to find them out by trial and error. It is a pain, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the pre-built binaries, link against the static, monolithic, mt build of Allegro. You'll need to adjust your compiler settings to match (/MT) and add `ALLEGRO_STATICLINK` to your list of preprocessor definitions.

If you do that, then you only need to distribute your executable file and your resources (images, sounds, etc).

Note that you should have at least two configurations: Debug & Release. When working on your application, you should use the Debug configuration (linking against the regular debug Allegro library). When distributing your application, you should use the Release configuration.