# How to make an allegro 4 game portable

Tags: c, include-path, allegro4

So, I have this game that was my university project during the first period and I wanted to make it portable so it can run on any computer, even if the allegro library and gnu are not installed on them. This is the link to the project git repository: https://github.com/HenriqueSabino/IpProject

The command line I'm using to compile it is the following:
`gcc -Wl,--subsystem,windows -I libs/include/ -L libs/lib/ -g sources/*.c -o "build/Knights and Demons" -lallegro-4.4.2-monolith-md-debug res/resources.res`

But even though the allegro library is in the libs/lib folder, it does not run on other computers, an error messaging saying `the code execution cannot proceed because allegro-4.4.2-monolith-md-debug.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem`

How can I overcome this error? Thanks for helping

Comment: And **what** is the error message? [it looks like there is just a leading slash missing, or lib/ is implict]

Comment: @wildplasser `the code execution cannot proceed because allegro-4.4.2-monolith-md-debug.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem`

Comment: Well, that would indicate that a) you're deploying the debugging version, not the release version (see the *debug* in the dll name) and b) that you're not deploying that DLL file (or another DLL that it depends on). But you shouldn't be distributing debug builds as a general rule.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to remove the debugging version and will reply to you asap

Comment: Using the non-debug version is no help, but how do I know the dlls I need to include? PS: I only extracted the allegro library and put it in the libs folder

Comment: Currently trying to solve the issue with dependency walker after reading this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948915/running-allegro-5-on-other-computers, if it works I'm gonna close the question

Comment: Ok, problem solved, thanks @wildplasser for helping me out :)